# How I can select all gruop of the Active Directory?

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

I want to select information of the AD. I need to know, which groups are the Views and the User who has access these Views.

This query, I have information about Users

```
SELECT
       *
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI,'<LDAP://DC=dominio,DC=com,DC=br>;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user));
     sn,
    sAMAccountName,
    displayName,
    mail,
    telephoneNumber,
    mobile,
    physicalDeliveryOfficeName,
    department,
    division;
    subtree')
```

*P.S.:Edit if you think necessary*

Answer (score 0):

If you want groups instead of users, then change this:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))
```

to this:

```
(objectClass=group)
```

And change the list of attributes to whatever you want to see. The list of members is in an attribute called "member".

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution of my case.

```
(&(objectClass=group)(memberOF=CN="ViewName",OU="FolderName",OU="...",DC=dominio,DC=com,DC=br)
```

Need to know the structure in the Active Directory. Need create OU for every folder of way that is in AD.